# How does AirDrop retain "Developer Verification" information? And, can this be done with other methods?

Tags: macos, applications, sharing, airdrop

I am trying to share an app. AirDrop successfully completed this task. However, when e-mail is used, the error regarding an unknown developer prevents the app from running. Why is AirDrop successful and e-mail not?

Is there something I can do to share the app and retain the developer information?

Answer (score 1):

Apps are actually containers, if the container doesn't contain a verified developer certificate then you will see that message pop-up when you try to open the app.

If you right click and select open it will still let you open the app, irregardless if it is from a verified developer or not.